# Return list index from a list of tidygraph objects in R?

Tags: r, tidygraph

So, I have a list of multiple `tidygraph` objects and what Im trying to do is return the index a specific `tidygraph` object, selected by the user. Hopefully my example below will explain the problem.

(ASIDE: I have attempted a solution that I show below, but at the moment it is super slow to run. Im hoping to come up with a different, faster solution.)

To begin, I create some data to turn into `tidygraph` objects, then I create the `tidygraph` objects and put them all together into a list:

```
library(tidygraph)

# create some data for the tbl_graph
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Hadley", "David", "Romain", "Julia"),
                    level = c(1,1,1,1),
                    rank = c(1,1,1,1))

nodes1 <- data.frame(name = c("Hadley", "David", "Romain", "Julia"),
                    level = c(1,1,1,1),
                    rank = c(2,2,2,2))

nodes2 <- data.frame(name = c("Hadley", "David", "Romain", "Julia"),
                    level = c(1,1,1,1),
                    rank = c(3,3,3,3))

nodes3 <- data.frame(name = c("Hadley", "David", "Romain", "Julia"),
                    level = c(2,2,2,2),
                    rank = c(1,1,1,1))


edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                    to = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3))


# create the tbl_graphs
tg <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)
tg_1 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes1, edges = edges)
tg_2 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes2, edges = edges)
tg_3 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes3, edges = edges)

# put into list
myList <- list(tg, tg_1, tg_2, tg_3)
```

For clarity, looking at the 1st list element looks like this:

```
> myList[1]
[[1]]
# A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 9 edges
#
# A directed simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 4 × 3 (active)
  name   level  rank
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Hadley     1     1
2 David      1     1
3 Romain     1     1
4 Julia      1     1
#
# Edge Data: 9 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     1     4
# … with 6 more rows
```

We can see that each object has a variable called `level` and another called `rank`. What Im trying to do is return the list index of an object by selecting the `level` and `rank` number. So, for example, if I select `level = 1` and `rank = 2`, my function would return the index of the object with those values (in this case the 2nd list element). My attempted solution to this is below, but it's a very slow process... I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve what I want?

**My Attempted Solution**

In my solution, I begin by turning each of the `tidygraph` objects in a tibble to make them easier to manipulate. And this is why my function is so slow. In my data, I could have up to 200,000 `tidygraph` objects in a list, so going through them and converting them all to tibbles is a very slow process. I do that like so:

```
# seperating out the list to make it easier to manipulate
list_obj <- lapply(myList, function(x){
  edges <- tidygraph::activate(x, edges) %>% tibble::as_tibble()
  nodes <- tidygraph::activate(x, nodes) %>% tibble::as_tibble()
  return(list(edges = edges, nodes = nodes))
} )
```

And then this is the function I actually use to extract the index of the chosen object:

```
# this function returns the tree index asked for by user
getTreeListNumber <- function(listObj, level, rank){
  
  res <- 0
  listNumber <- NA
  
  for(i in 1:length(listObj)){
    res <- level %in% listObj[[i]]$nodes$level && rank %in% listObj[[i]]$nodes$rank
    if(res == TRUE){
      listNumber <- i
    }
  }
  return(listNumber)
}
```

For example:

```
> getTreeListNumber(list_obj, level = 1, rank = 2)
[1] 2
```

By selecting the level and rank, the function return the objects index within the list. But is there a faster way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try -

```
getTreeListNumber <- function(listObj, level, rank){
  which(sapply(myList, function(x) {
    nodes <- tidygraph::activate(x, nodes) %>% tibble::as_tibble() 
    all(nodes$level == level & nodes$rank == rank)
  }))
}

getTreeListNumber(myList, 1, 2)
#[1] 2
```

Comment: This is definitely much faster than my attempted solution. But with this way, I'm still turning everything into a tibble, which I feel could be avoided somehow.